# Creating a web3py contract -- TypeError: contract() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python, web3.py

```
from web3 import Web3
import json
from web3.providers.rpc import HTTPProvider
contractAddress = '0xmasked'
web3 = Web3(HTTPProvider('https://mainnet.infura.io'))
with open('contract.abi', 'r') as abi_definition:
    abi = json.load(abi_definition)


fContract = web3.eth.contract(abi,contractAddress)
```

Has anyone encountered the following error? From what I see I'm calling two arguments not three.

```
TypeError: contract() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Comment: could you print the variable abi and share the output ?

Comment: One more thing, suggest to connect to a testnet instead of mainnet in infura

Comment: Based on that message, it seems you are on web3.py version 4 (beta). Can you confirm the exact version?

Answer (score 1):

In web3.py v4 (which I'm guessing you're on, based on the error), only the address can be passed as a positional argument.

To resolve the issue, [initialize the contract](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.eth.html#web3.eth.Eth.contract) with the ABI passed as a keyword argument, like so:

```
fContract = web3.eth.contract(contractAddress, abi=abi)
```